# different date formats in different windows azure deployment environment

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, cultureinfo, regional-settings

I have two environments (Deployments) in Windows Azure.
In one environment (say D env) the statement

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")
```

returns  `"08-01-2013"`

and in another environment (say E env) it returns `"08/01/2013"`

I couldn't figure why it happening so.

Comment: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579608/windows-azure-having-troubles-with-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

I think your environments additional settings are different.

Your D environment uses date additional setting uses `-`, your E environment uses `/` Change your date format to `dd.MM.yyyy` in environment E.

For Windows 7, follow `Control Panel-->Language and Region-->Change the date, time and number format-->Additional Settings--> Date`

[image]

If you want to some changes in your code part, you can use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) property in your code.

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with
>   the English language but not with any country/region. You specify the
>   invariant culture by name by using an empty string ("") in the call to
>   a CultureInfo instantiation method. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture also
>   retrieves an instance of the invariant culture. It can be used in
>   almost any method in the System.Globalization namespace that requires
>   a culture.

Let's say you want to French `CultureInfo` for both environments.

```
CultureInfo frFr = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy", frFr);
```

Comment: Can I do what you are doing in UI using some configuration file in Windows Azure?

Comment: @SujithKp I never use Windows Azure but Is there any configuration options in Azure? Take a look for asp.net version http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162/en-us

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ToString` overload that uses settings from the current `Culture`. The slash character in your format string is treated as a replacement character for the current culture's date field separator.

If you want to use an explicit date format string, also use an explicit format provider. In this case I'd recommend using the format in the `InvariantCulture`; e.g.

```
using System.Globalization;
...
var x = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also modify the format string to use an explicit slash, by enclosing it in single quotes. This stops the parser from attempting to find a cultural replacement character:

```
var x = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'mm'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: The problem with this approach in my context is that DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") is heavily used. So I don't want to change everywhere when it is already working in E env(which is our target env.).