# Windows Azure having troubles with date format

Tags: azure

I'm having a lot of trouble deploying a website on windows azure... with dates and money formats, for example. My question is: It is possible to change the server's culture, or do I have to change my entire app to fits the azure location settings?

Works fine on servers with Latin American standards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add something like this to your web.config (in the system.web section):

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

You can find the appropriate identifier in the [CultureInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to change the culture settings in your application.  Here's a similar thread - [Currency settings in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858120/currency-settings-in-azure)