# Jquery datepicker returning invalid date message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get up and running a Date of Birth field for an application. Firstly I have created a model which contains the below

Model

```
 [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Date of Birth")]
    //This is to set the DOB into a day Month Year format
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Next I have the controller which is a simple create.

Controller

```
 // POST: Customers/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerId,FirstName,MiddleName,Surname,DOB,Gender,Address,AddressL2,Town,Postcode,Phone,Email")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Import the libphoneNumber class
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
            PhoneNumber n = phoneUtil.Parse(customer.Phone, "GB");

            customer.PhoneNumberFormatted = phoneUtil.Format(n, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);


            customer.CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customer);
    }
```

And lastly my view with the Jquery running for a datepicker to work.

```
  @model Phase5.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressL2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressL2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressL2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Town, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Town, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Town, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Postcode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postcode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    $("#DOB").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: Date.parse("1900-01-01"),
            maxDate: Date.parse("2100-01-01"),
            yearRange: "c-90:c+150"
        });

        // validation in case user types the date out of valid range from keyboard : To fix the bug with out of range date time while saving in sql
        $(function () {
            $.validator.addMethod(
                "date",
                function (value, element) {

                    var minDate = Date.parse("1900-01-01");
                    var maxDate = Date.parse("2100-01-01");
                    var valueEntered = Date.parse(value);

                    if (valueEntered < minDate || valueEntered > maxDate) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(minDate));
                },
                "Please enter a valid date!"
            );
        });
</script>
}
```

The issue I am getting is majority of dates that I have used for testing are returning with an error message 'The value '13/10/1986' is not valid for Date of Birth.'

I have tried this on a localhost and it seems to work without any issues but since publishing it to my site it fails

Many thanks

Comment: Try adding the date format in your datepicker.

Comment: $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy" );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer is nothing to do with the code yet the way in which the server is configured.

you will need to use

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

and put this in the web.config in system.web section

[Windows Azure having troubles with date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579608/windows-azure-having-troubles-with-date-format)

Works fine now

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem recently when i published my website to azure, date format was different on server (mm/dd/yyyy), so you can change date format maybe it could be issue. Good luck